# vb6 create an object twice, will cause memory leakage or not?

Tags: vb6

I just want to check if I write following codes in vb6:

```
dim a as new b
dim a as new b
```

will it cause the memory leak or not?

Comment: Note that it is usually a poor idea to use `As New` unless you understand its side efects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code won't even compile because you are defining A twice.

However, in this example:

```
Dim A As B
Set A = New B
Set A = New B
```

After the third line, the first instance of B stored in A on the second line will be destroyed.

Comment: A will not be destroyed, because it will never have been instantiated. Variables declared "As New" are instantiated "just in time" when you call a method or property, or pass the variable into a parameter.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw Albeit I completely believe you (since I never used that syntax due to the late binding issue), do you have a test case or proof or documentation of such?

Comment: @PhoenixX_2 It is so long ago since I used the official documentation! But you can test this by adding a Watch to c in the following - note that it is never displayed as "Nothing": Dim c As New Collection: Debug.Print c.Count: Set c = Nothing: Debug.Print TypeName(c)

Answer (score 2):

No, this will not cause a memory leak.

You can also put this code in a loop of 10000 iterations and look at your memory in Task Manager.